# How can I get Manipulate[] graphics to print when batch printing notebooks?

Tags: manipulate, pdf-format, automation

I want to print Manipulate[] graphics while batch printing several notebooks.  Here's the long version:

I have several Manipulate[] graphics cells in my notebooks.  The only way I know of to get the graphics to appear in PDF output is to open the notebook, evaluate it, and then save to PDF.  If I close my notebook after evaluating the cells with Manipulate[] graphics in them, when I reopen the notebook the graphics are gone.

Now I want to process an entire directory of ~20 notebooks with one command.  I thought that by opening the notebooks with NotebookOpen[] then evaluating them with NotebookEvaluate[] before running NotebookPrint[notebook,"filename.pdf"] that would get the Manipulate[] graphics to print to PDF.

Unfortunately, that didn't work.  I get huge gray boxes with manipulator controls instead of the graphics images.

This is the code I'm using:

```
allToPDF[] := Module[{inDir, outDir, nbFileNames, toPDF}
  , inDir = SetDirectory@NotebookDirectory[];
  outDir = inDir <> "PDF";
  nbFileNames = FileNames["review*.nb"];
  toPDF[nbFileName_] := Module[{outFileName, inFileName, nb}
    , inFileName = NotebookDirectory[] <> "\\"  nbFileName;
    outFileName = 
     inDir  "\\PDF\\" <> FileBaseName[nbFileName] <> ".pdf";
    If[FileExistsQ[
       outFileName] \[And] (FileDate[inFileName] <
        FileDate[outFileName]), Return[]];
    nb = NotebookOpen[inFileName];
    NotebookEvaluate[nb];
    NotebookPrint[nb, outFileName];
    NotebookClose[nb]
    ];
  toPDF[#] & /@ nbFileNames
  ]
allToPDF[]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider this. I have 3 notebooks, `{"nb1.nb", "nb2.nb", "nb3.nb"}` which for the sake of testing all have a simple `Manipulate` object. If I follow your method, they print a grey box.

Below I suggest a method to achieve what you're after,

## Turn on `TrustByDefault`

By default, your FE hides Dynamic content (giving grey boxes until you accept the Dynamic Warning dialog). To get around this, you want to set the Global option `"TrustByDefault"` to `True`:

```
    SetOptions[$FrontEnd, {"NotebookSecurityOptions" -> {"TrustByDefault" -> True}}]
    (* Press "Yes" in the dialog that appears *)
```

I would recommend setting this back to Automatic when you complete your evaluation.

## Print notebooks in bulk

#### Line by line...

Set Directory:

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
```

Locate files to print:

```
filesToPrint = FileNames["nb*"]
(*{"nb1.nb", "nb2.nb", "nb3.nb"}*)
```

Open the 3 files. Note the `Visible -> False`, so your screen isn't filled with 20 Notebooks:

```
nbs = NotebookOpen[NotebookDirectory[] <> "\\" <> #, 
   Visible -> False] & /@ filesToPrint;
```

Feed the `NotebookObject`s and the file names to `NotebookPrint` to print the open (albeit invisible) notebooks:

```
NotebookPrint[#[[1]], 
   NotebookDirectory[] <> "\\" <> #[[2]] <> ".pdf"] & /@ 
 Transpose[{nbs, filesToPrint}]
```

Close the opened notebooks:

```
NotebookClose /@ nbs;
```

#### Altogether:

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
filesToPrint = FileNames["nb*"]
nbs = NotebookOpen[NotebookDirectory[] <> "\\" <> #, 
     Visible -> False] & /@ filesToPrint;
NotebookPrint[#[[1]], 
    NotebookDirectory[] <> "\\" <> #[[2]] <> ".pdf"] & /@ 
  Transpose[{nbs, filesToPrint}];
NotebookClose /@ nbs
```

Now for every "nb*.nb" file, we have a "nb*.nb.pdf":

```
FileNames[]
(*{"nb1.nb", "nb1.nb.pdf", "nb2.nb", "nb2.nb.pdf", "nb3.nb", \
"nb3.nb.pdf", "print.nb"}*)
```

And don't forget to set `"TrustByDefault"` back:

```
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, {"NotebookSecurityOptions" -> {"TrustByDefault" \
-> Automatic}}]
```

I'll leave it as an exercise for the reader to compile this into a function, if desired.